# Optimize triplet summation

Tags: c++, performance

I need to compute the summation of:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\text{sum of triplets}}{\text{product of triplets}}\right\rfloor$$

from integers of an array.

Input:

```
5

1 2 1 7 3
```

Output:

```
6
```

Explanation:

> The following triplets exists in the given array:
>
> 1 2 1
>
> 1 2 7
>
> 1 2 3
>
> 1 1 7
>
> 1 1 3
>
> 1 7 3
>
> 2 1 7
>
> 2 1 3
>
> 2 7 3
>
> 1 7 3
>
> Considering these triplets from the sample input:
>
> 1 2 1 contributes 2 [floor{(1+2+1)/(1*2*1)} = floor{4/2}=2]
>
> 1 2 3 contributes 1
>
> 1 1 7 contributes 1
>
> 1 1 3 contributes 1
>
> 2 1 3 contributes 1
>
> All other triplets contribute 0 to the sum.
>
> Hence the answer is (2+1+1+1+1)=6.

What I tried has complexity \$O(n^3)\$:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long t,n[300005],sum=0,mul=1,i,j,k,res=0;
    cin >> t;

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        cin >>n[i];


    for(i=0;i<t-2;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j<t-1;j++)
    for(k=j+1;k<t;k++)
    {
        sum = n[i]+n[j]+n[k];
        mul = n[i]*n[j]*n[k];
        res += floor(sum/mul);
    }

    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any hint of better optimization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Can be done in \$O(n)\$ time

You can do better than \$O(n^3)\$ if you think about what kinds of triplets give nonzero contributions.  First of all, any triplet that does not contain a 1 will contribute zero to the final answer.  Next, if you examine all the triplets that contain 1, there are 5 types of triplets that contribute nonzero amounts to the answer:

1. `1 1 1` contributes 3
2. `1 1 2` contributes 2
3. `1 1 X` contributes 1, where `X > 2`
4. `1 2 2` contributes 1
5. `1 2 3` contributes 1

So you can get an \$O(n)\$ solution by counting all the 1s 2s and 3s in the input.  Then you can compute the number of each of the 5 types of triplets above by using simple combinatorics.

#### Sample \$O(n)\$ solution

Here is a sample solution based on the above.  Notice I removed the entire input array because all that is needed is the counts:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long n   = 0;
    long c1  = 0;
    long c2  = 0;
    long c3  = 0;
    long res = 0;

    std::cin >> n;
    for(long i=0;i<n;i++) {
        long num;
        std::cin >> num;
        if (num == 1)
            c1++;
        else if (num == 2)
            c2++;
        else if (num == 3)
            c3++;
    }

    // Count all the {1, 1, 1} triplets.  There are (c1 choose 3),
    // each contributing 3:
    res += ((c1 * (c1-1) * (c1-2)) / 6) * 3;

    // Count all the {1, 1, 2} triplets.  There are (c1 choose 2) * c2
    // combinations, each contributing 2:
    res += ((c1 * (c1-1)) / 2) * c2 * 2;

    // Count all the {1, 1, X} triplets, where X > 2.  There are
    // (c1 choose 2) * (n - c1 - c2) combinations, each contributing 1:
    res += ((c1 * (c1-1)) / 2) * (n - c1 - c2);

    // Count all the {1, 2, 2} triplets.  There are c1 * (c2 choose 2)
    // combinations, each contributing 1:
    res += c1 * ((c2 * (c2-1)) / 2);

    // Count all the {1, 2, 3} triplets.  There are c1 * c2 * c3
    // combinations, each contributing 1:
    res += c1 * c2 * c3;

    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this program can be optimized even further by combining some of the expressions, but I wrote it in the way that most clearly demonstrates where each part of the answer came from.

Answer (score 1):

You should analyze the problem before you start writing code.

What is the difference between the sum/product of the kth subarray and the (k+1)th subarray. Lets say that the variable `int sum` holds the value of the kth subarray, then you get the value of the next one via

```
sum  += n[k+3] - n[k];
prod /= n[k];
prod *= n[k+3];
```

Note that i split the calculation of prod as there might be rounding errors otherwise. So that should give you an idea about what to write.

Generally you code is terrible to look at.

1. Do not use `namespace std;` It is bad practice
2. Use descriptive names. For example your variable `t` should be named `arrayLength` or something in that direction. That applies for every other variable.
3. Why are you allocating an large array if you know the size of the array. Also you should use a `std::vector` or `std::array`. Your input routine then becomes.

   ```
   size_t lengthArray;
   std::cin >> lengthArray;

   std::vector<size_t> data(lengthArray);
   for (auto &elem : data) {
       std::cin >> elem;
   }
   ```
4. Declare variables where you need them. This is not ancient c where you declare everything at the beginning of the function.
5. Stick with a given code style stuff like this is just terrible

   ```
   for(i=0;i<t-2;i++)
   for(j=i+1;j<t-1;j++)
   for(k=j+1;k<t;k++)
   {
       sum = n[i]+n[j]+n[k];
       mul = n[i]*n[j]*n[k];
       res += floor(sum/mul);
   }
   ```

   As a rule of thumb always use braces in nested statements.
6. You only need one loop that goes over the array once so start with determining the sum/product of the first subarray. Also if you use unsigned data, then the result is automatically rounded down for you.

   ```
   size_t sum  = data[0]+data[1]+data[2];
   size_t prod = data[0]*data[1]*data[2];
   size_t res  = sum/prod;

   for (unsigned i = 0; i < arrayLength-3; ++i) {
       sum  += data[k+3] - data[k]; 
       prod /= data[k];
       prod *= data[k+3];
       res  += sum/prod;
   }
   std::cout << res;
   ```

Comment: He actually wants all possible triplets in the array, not triplets in the first traverse.

Comment: That is true, sorry i misread. However, the principle stays the same. You can keep the last sum/product and use the intermediate value afterwards. Although it is slightly overoptimized for a subarray of length 3. I will correct the code late the evening